# Export Data to CSV using SSIS causing datatype changed

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have a SSIS package to export the table datas to CSV. However I have a string column with values '000' and '001' and '004'. When I am writting into the CSV using FlatFile connection the values are changed to 0,1 and 4.

However I have mentioned the columns as DT_STR with length of 3.

Could anyone help me to print the values as string.?

I am totally clueless.

Regards,
saravanakumar

Comment: How are you writing it? What is the output and input column type?

Comment: @shree.pat18 I am writting using Flag File connection in DFT. The output Column and Input columns are DW_STR of size 3 only.

Comment: And table column is also a string type?

Comment: Are you opening the csv file in a text editor or in excel?

Comment: @Jayvee - I am opening the document in excel only.

Comment: I have opened the CSV in Notepad. its looks it printed correctly in the CSV file itself. The problem is only with that MS Excel it seems.

Comment: @Sravan I've posted a couple of solutions I can think of as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to the representation in Excel. The solutions are either opening the document in another text editor or if it is required to open it in excel, then use an excel destination. An alternative solution is to generate the values in the csv as formulas, e.g. ="001",="002"... etc. as this will keep the leading zeros when opening in excel.